# how to replicate to and replicate from to remote databases, pouchdb to couchbase

Tags: angularjs, couchbase, pouchdb

I am using Angular(js) and pouchdb as local db and couchbase as remote database.
angularjs code

```
.run(function ($pouchDB) {
    $pouchDB.setDatabase("local");
    $pouchDB.replicateFrom("http://couchbaseServer/office");
    $pouchDB.replicateTo("http://couchbaseServer/mobile");
})



 //pouchDB service code
         this.replicateTo = function(remoteDB) {
            database.replicate.to(remoteDB).on('complete', function () {
          // yay, we're done!
          alert("replicationTo done");
            }).on('error', function (err) {
              // boo, something went wrong!
              alert("data was not replicated to server, error - " + err);
            });
        };

        this.replicateFrom = function(remoteDB) {
            database.replicate.from(remoteDB).on('complete', function () {
          // yay, we're done!
          alert("replicationFrom done");
            }).on('error', function (err) {
              // boo, something went wrong!
              alert("data was not replicated from server, error - " + err);
            });
        };
```

i get an error on the replicate to, invalid doc id

this is replicating everything to prove the concept. My next question will be to filter the replicate to data to only the data generated locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to replicate data from PouchDB or CouchbaseLite for that matter you would need a synchronizing service which called "Sync Gateway".

SyncGateway implements the CouchDB replication interface and enables the replication.

more info can be found [here](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.2/develop/guides/sync-gateway/index.html) and [here](https://pouchdb.com/faq.html)

Comment: thank you for your response, sorry i did not mention that i do have sync gateway running and it works with one database just fine. My question is how to code the replicate to on one database and the replicate from on the other. the from data is different than the to data.  thanks